# How can I fetch a mail and mark it as seen at once?

Tags: email, imap, imaplib

I'm reading an inbox, fetching emails, and marking each of them as seen.

Code goes as below:

```
self.mail.select()  # default=INBOX
typ, msgnums = self.mail.uid('search', 'SINCE %s' % today)

for uid in msgnums:
    typ, rfc = self.mail.uid('fetch', num, '(RFC822)')
    self.mail.uid('STORE', num, '+FLAGS', '(\\Seen)')  # This line seems to take some time
```

However, it seems that fetching and storing one by one takes time.

When I remove that `'STORE'` line, the program runs much faster.

So, I wonder if there is a way to mark a mail as seen when fetching it.

Something like, `self.mail.uid('fetch', num, '(RFC822)', MARK_AS_SEEN)`..

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: That precise `fetch` command you're sending already does set the \seen flag. `rfc822` is an alias for `body[]`, which means the whole body and set the \seen flag. `body.peek[]` means just the whole body, without the flag change. Things typically go much, much faster if you cut down the number of commands, though, so I suggest retrieving all of the bodies using a single command instead of using a loop.

Comment: @arnt Thanks for the comment. So you mean that code should have changed the flag as seen? But it didn't for me.. weird.. Can I confirm it with an additional option, not relying on the default option?

Comment: I suppose you could use `body[]` instead of `rfc822`, but either should work, unless there's a server bug. Servers aren't bugfree, but this particular server bug would be rather surprising.

Comment: Both bring the same result... Thanks!